# Does 'Ubuntu One Mobile' support Ogg Vorbis?

Tags: file-format, android, ubuntu-one

The standard audio-format for music in Rhythmbox is Ogg. For some reason none of my music encoded as OggVorbis shows up in the Ubuntu One Mobile Music application on my Android phone. The MP3s do show up. It looks like the Ubuntu One servers are not indexing Ogg-files, although it is THE open format for music with superior quality to MP3 and Ubuntu's Rhythmbox encoded my CDs to that format. Solution?

Comment: Can your Android play Ogg Vorbis?  (I'm not sure what formats they tend to support?)

Comment: Ogg is natively supported on my Xperia X10 with Android 1.6 and I don't think this is something that Sony added! So it might be a bug in the synchronization. For testing you can maybe try to rename a .mp3 to .ogg.. The player will properly ignore the extension anyway!

Answer (score 17):

We've just released ogg support on devices that support it (Android, Ubuntu).

There are 2 things that held back ogg support in our first release:

- iPhone does not support ogg (we would need to build per-os music libraries, which added a lot of complexity and time)
- Battery life for ogg was pretty bad, as it wasn't using hardware to decode the stream. we need to do more research in this area

We also surveyed mimetypes of our existing users, and only a *very* small percentage of people had ogg files  (I do understand the chicken-and-egg situation).

Comment: As a follow up, we're making good progress in adding ogg streaming support for Android devices. It will likely not be available to test before Jan, but some progress has been made  :)

Comment: So, we just completed a first initial round of testing, and it went well. We managed to stream to Android phones, found a bug in older versions which we've fixed. Things are looking good, but I can't yet say when we'd be able to do a public launch.

Comment: feel free to edit your posts to add updates like this (comments can get a bit hidden) :)

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu One Mobile only currently supports the streaming of MP3 files, but may support open codecs like OGG and FLAC in the future.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhatAudioFormatsAreSupported

Comment: Change the "will" to a "might", and you're absolutely correct. We are evaluating many things, and will not get to do them all.