# Ogg support for Ubuntu Music App

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does 'Ubuntu One Mobile' support Ogg Vorbis?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13790/does-ubuntu-one-mobile-support-ogg-vorbis)

I've just paid for Ubuntu Music and downloaded the app for my Android phone, but it appears Ogg Vorbis files are not supported. This is a definite deal breaker and I think I'm going to cancel until this is added, unless this feature is imminent. How soon is this likely to be added?

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed here:

[Does 'Ubuntu One Mobile' support Ogg Vorbis?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13790/does-ubuntu-one-mobile-support-ogg-vorbis)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link  - disappointing. I guess from that it might not even happen. Can I suggest that you change all the info enticing people to subscribe, as at no point does that mention which file types are supported, and as a Ubuntu user I naturally assumed that Oggs were supported. It's a bit misleading.