# Can Ubuntu One mobile stream FLAC files or other audio types or just mp3?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I was reading the tech specs at https://one.ubuntu.com/mobile/ and the title says it all.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're currently working on adding more file formats (ogg and m4a). We have absolutely no plans of adding FLAC support. For updates to ogg support you can subscribe to the feed on [Does 'Ubuntu One Mobile' support Ogg Vorbis?](https://askubuntu.com/q/13790/711).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Thats too bad that there is no chance for FLAC support. But if it doesn't support it will it get some sort of conversion or will audiophiles with FLAC heavy music just be screwed?

Comment: that's an excellent question, and one I can't answer definitely right now.